# Responsive DIV with with video inside

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and CSS that I need to make responsive.

It starts with a lightweight YouTube video embedding (less YouTube code to download) found from labnol.org.  I then wrapped the youtube-player div with two other divs to horizontally center the video.

I've tried a few solutions I've seen here in SO, but have not been able to make this work.  I would like to be able to set the max width in any display, but not have it go off the edge of the screen when viewed on mobile devices.

I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div id="videoParent" class="videoParent">
<div id="videoDiv" class="videoDiv">
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="gmX8VFlrv38"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS.

```
<style>
    <style>
    .videoDiv {
         max-width:560px;
         display:inline-block;
         width:90%;

    }
    .videoParent {
          text-align:center;
    }

        .youtube-player {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 56.23%;
            /* Use 75% for 4:3 videos */
            height: 0;
            /*width:400px; */
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 100%;
            background: #000;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .youtube-player iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
            z-index: 100;
            background: transparent;
        }

        .youtube-player img {
            bottom: 0;
            display: block;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            border: none;
            height: auto;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition: .4s all;
            -moz-transition: .4s all;
            transition: .4s all;
        }

        .youtube-player img:hover {
            -webkit-filter: brightness(75%);
        }

        .youtube-player .play {
            height: 72px;
            width: 72px;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -36px;
            margin-top: -36px;
            position: absolute;
            background: url("//i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png") no-repeat;
            cursor: pointer;
        }</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified my CSS to the following at it appears to be doing what I need it to.

```
.videoParent {
      text-align:center;
}
.videoDiv {
     max-width:560px;
     display:inline-block;
     width:60%;
   }
```